# Getting the directory name in java

Tags: java, file-io

How do I get the directory name for a particular `java.io.File` on the drive in Java?

For example I have a file called `test.java` under a directory on my D drive.

I want to return the directory name for this file.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
File file = new File("d:/test/test.java");
File parentDir = file.getParentFile(); // to get the parent dir 
String parentDirName = file.getParent(); // to get the parent dir name
```

Remember, `java.io.File` represents directories as well as files.

Comment: @skaffman Don't I get the parent directory name from file's pathname?

Comment: Did not work for me. getParent() returns null.

Answer (score 18):

With Java 7 there is yet another way of doing this:

```java
Path path = Paths.get("d:/test/test.java"); 
Path parent = path.getParent();
//getFileName() returns file name for 
//files and dir name for directories
String parentDirName = path.getFileName().toString();
```

I (slightly) prefer this way, because one is manipulating path rather than files, which imho better shows the intentions. You can read about the differences between File and Path in the [Legacy File I/O Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) tutorial

Answer (score 10):

Note also that if you create a file this way (supposing "d:/test/" is current working directory):

```
File file = new File("test.java");
```

You might be surprised, that both getParentFile() and getParent() return null. Use these to get parent directory no matter how the File was created:

```
File parentDir = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
String parentDirName = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent();
```

Comment: This answer gets my green check.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("d:/test/test.java");
String dirName = file.getParentFile().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that you have a file called `test.java` in `C:\\myfolder` directory. Using the below code, you can find the directory where that file sits.

```
String fileDirectory = new File("C:\\myfolder\\test.java").getAbsolutePath(); 
fileDirectory = fileDirectory.substring(0,fileDirectory.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

This code will give the output as `C:\\myfolder`