# How to get the folder path where the file exist from file path?

Tags: java, android

Suppose my file path is "/path/to/file/foo.txt". i want to get "/path/to/file" . means i want to get the path to the folder only where my file exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking us for code without trying it ownself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the directory name in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009981/getting-the-directory-name-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/foo.txt");
System.out.println(file.getParent());
```

**edit**

Find the reated Java doc here: [File.html#getParent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getParent())

Answer (score 1):

Refer the post: [How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197049/how-to-get-just-the-parent-directory-name-of-a-specific-file)

Use [`File`'s `getParentFile()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) and `String.lastIndexOf()` to retrieve *just* the immediate parent directory.

Mark's comment is a better solution than`lastIndexOf()`:

```
file.getParentFile().getName();
```

These solutions only works if the file has a parent file (e.g., created via one of the file constructors taking a parent `File`). When `getParentFile()` is null you'll need to resort to using `lastIndexOf`, or use something like [Apache Commons' `FileNameUtils.getFullPath()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getFullPath%28java.lang.String%29):

```
FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(file.getAbsolutePath());
=> C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
```

There are several variants to retain/drop the prefix and trailing separator. You can either use the same `FilenameUtils` class to grab the name from the result, use `lastIndexOf`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/foo.txt");
file.getAbsolutePath();
```